# C# - RadGrid Rebind In Control Outside of RadGrid

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, telerik, radgrid

I have a RadGrid control. When I call RadGrid.Rebind() in its sorting/filter event handlers the data updates. When I call rebind() within a linkbutton outside the RadGrid, NeedDataSource is triggered and the datasource is changed appropriately but the RadGrid itself doesn't update the cell values with the new datasource. The only way I can get it to refresh is by manually refeshing the browser.

Does anybody have any ideas why this happens?

(Using Telerik AJAX Controls for .NET)

EDIT: My Linkbutton wasn't wrapped in a RadAjaxPanel. I have now put this in the markup around the RadGrid and the linkbutton. Nothing is happening..I don;t see how this will change things..surely  I have to do something with this RadAjaxPanel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are the controls all wrapped in a RadAjaxPanel, or does the LinkButton update the RadGrid if you are using RadAjaxManager?

If you wrap the grid and the linkbutton in a RadAjaxPanel it should work.

Comment: Could you be a little mor especific...I have wrapped the link button and the grid in RadAjaxPanels in markup....do I have to do anything else?

Comment: Are they in the same radajaxpanel?

Comment: no that isn't a possibility. the link button is an asp:content tag and must go at the top of markup.

Comment: Then you would need to add a RadAjaxManager that allows the one ajaxpanel to update the other ajaxpanel (one with link can update the one with the grid). For example - http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/ajax-controls-in-ajaxpanel-and-ajaxsettings.html

Comment: I ended up using a RadManagerProxy as I had a RadManager already defined in a parent aspx page. Your answer led me to the wprking solution. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

If you're using a `RadAjaxPanel` or the `RadAjaxManager`, you'll need to make sure that the `LinkButton` is either in a `RadAjaxPanel` or defined as a setting in the manager, with the RadGrid as one of the `UpdatedControls`.